# php in_array with strings containing "&" or "space" in php

Tags: php

I have an array like :

```
$array = array('a & b' => 'A & B', 'c & d'=>'C & D');

$string = 'a & b';
```

when I do `in_array(ucwords($string),$array)` I get FALSE
if I do  `array_key_exists($string, $array)` I also get FALSE

any idea?
thanks

Update: it seems that the way I collected $string is where the problem was ( using fuelphp Uri:: Segment(3) ) though visually  the string collected seems identical for some reason it is not. Thanks for your quick input

Comment: Works here: http://codepad.org/ZWXn9Wlh.... your code actually gives an error, because you missed `array`, but it does not return `false`.

Comment: you have edited your code, but now it will return true on both the function, so what's your actual problem?

Comment: Thanks Felix, it seems like my problem comes from somewhere else mainly how I collect my $string variable. thanks for your help

Comment: I get my $string from the url using fuelphp Uri::segment()...I have to see why is the variable it returns not identical even if it seems that way

Answer (score 1):

Your `$array` is not actually an array?

```
$array = array('a & b' => 'A & B', 'c & d' => 'C & D');
```

Instead of:

```
$array = ('a & b' => 'A & B', 'c & d' => 'C & D');
```

Answer (score 1):

It works as one would expect for me: http://codepad.org/U1WtWiGe

The problem with your code is that you've missed the `array` keyword infront of your array and thus it will not be an array.

```
$array = array('a & b' => 'A & B', 'c & d' => 'C & D');
         ^^^^^
```

On a side note I'm a bit surprised you've even managed it to run as you would get a parse error with the code you provided.